# How to refresh a <p:graphicImage> from clicking a <p:commandButton>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ejb-3.0

hi I have a problem in changing the time knew buttone click on  the contents of the xhtml page does not change.

---

```
<h:form id="f">
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
          <p:commandButton value="Click " actionListener="#   {graphicImageView.test()}"  >
               <p:ajax update="img"   immediate="true"/>
          </p:commandButton>
          <p:graphicImage id="img" value="#{graphicImageView.chart}" cache="true" rendered="true" />
     </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

---

```
public PieDataset test() throws ParseException, IOException {
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date datee1;
    Date datee2;
    String date1 = "2014-06-01";
    String date2 = "2014-10-05";
    datee1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(date1);
    datee2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(date2);
    dataset.setValue("corectif", ifl.countexterne(true, datee1, datee2));
    dataset.setValue("Preventif", ifl.countexterne(false, datee1, datee2));

    return dataset;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one:

```
<h:form id="f">
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
          <p:commandButton value="Click " action="#{graphicImageView.test()}" update="img"></p:commandButton>
          <p:graphicImage id="img" value="#{graphicImageView.chart}" cache="true" rendered="true" />
     </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**NOTE:** `commandButton` itself has `ajax` call by default when we click on the button, so no need to use additional `p:ajax` tag.